# terraform init creating empty tfstate file

Tags: terraform

When i am doing terraform init commands, TF is not having the tfstate ( my tfstate file is in s3 bucket ). Also i am not able to see the terraform backend-config file inside the .terraform folder.

I am using terraform 0.10.4 version

---

Outputs:

```sh
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.10.4
    
$ terraform init \

-lock="true"
-backend-config="bucket=$TF_STATE_BUCKET"
-backend-config="key=$TF_STATE_KEY"
-backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TF_LOCK_TABLE"
-backend-config="region=$AWS_REGION"
-backend-config="profile=$AWS_PROFILE"
-backend-config="encrypt=true"
.
Downloading modules...
Get: git::ssh://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/add/tf-vpc.git?ref=1.0.1
Get: git::ssh://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/add/tf-ec-redis.git?ref=1.1.3
Get: git::ssh://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/add/tf-rds-pg.git?ref=1.3.0

Initializing provider plugins...
    
Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...
Downloading plugin for provider "aws" (0.1.4)...
    
The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration, so the latest version was installed.
    
To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings suggested below.

provider.aws: version = "~> 0.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

$ ll -al .terraform/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 XXXXX 1049089 0 Sep 12 18:10 modules/
drwxr-xr-x 1 XXXXX 1049089 0 Sep 12 18:10 plugins/
```

In present location TF will take the backup of the s3-tfstate file, but it's not there.

Comment: $ terraform refresh  
Empty or non-existent state file.  

Refresh will do nothing. Refresh does not error or return an erroneous
exit status because many automation scripts use refresh, plan, then apply
and may not have a state file yet for the first run.

Outputs:
dev_private_zone_name = XXXXXXXXXX.local
private_zone_name = XXXXXXXXXX.local

Answer (score 2):

This is expect behaviour after 0.9.x. The local tfstate file at `.terraform/terraform.tfstate` is almost an  empty file.  The only change is the serial number in it. It keeps increasing.

```
"serial": 1,
```

If you don't run `terraform apply`, the remote tfstate file will not be updated. If you never run `terraform apply`, the remote tfstate file is not exist.

So try to make some changes, then check the remote tfstate file (in your case, it is `s3://$TF_STATE_BUCKET/$TF_STATE_KEY`), you should see the difference.

Comment: As your comments, i have modified the tfstate file seriel to 1 and uploaded to s3 bucket, then i as usually i run terraform commands, again TF creating the Empty or non-existent state file.
-------------------------------------
output of commands : - 

`$ terraform refresh

Empty or non-existent state file.

Refresh will do nothing. Refresh does not error or return an erroneous
exit status because many automation scripts use refresh, plan, then apply
and may not have a state file yet for the first run.


Outputs:

output values....`

Comment: And one more information, tfstate file not created in .terraform folder.

Comment: `terraform.tfstate` file will be created in `.terraform` folder, but no resource information in it.

Comment: `terraform.tfstate` file is not created in .terraform folder. see the below, only module adn plugin are there. 
[ $ ls .terraform/ 
-------
modules/  plugins/ ]

Comment: if you run `init` properly with backend config, you don't need manually upload the tfstate file to s3 bucket. So there are something wrong in your environment. The init command you pasted, looks fine for me.

Comment: Yes. my `init` commands is fine, but i am facing this issue. not sure how to fix,.